# Why doesn’t the screen turn off when playing music

Tags: windows-xp, power, windows-media-player

I often listen to music on windows media player. I have screen set to turn off after 10 minutes. However, it doesn’t turn off when music is playing. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tools -> Options -> Player Tab -> Allow screen saver during playback`