# Windows 7 directly turn monitor off when just listening to music

Tags: windows-7, power-management, dell-xps

Windows 7, Laptop DELL XPS 1330:

When just listening to music, I want to turn off my laptop display **immediately**. It perfectly works after the usual delay (e.g. 10 mins) set in the power management, as described in question [Why doesn’t the screen turn off when playing music](https://superuser.com/questions/385960/why-doesnt-the-screen-turn-off-when-playing-music)

What I am looking for is a shortcut / key command to directly (manually) turn off the monitor, because why should I wait for 10 mins? So I directly want to "jump" in the state entered after 10 mins.

The idea is just to save battery for the first 10 mins.

Comment: In power management set 'do nothing' for 'on closing lid' and close you laptops lid when you are listening to music

Comment: Nice hint, but this "listening music scenario" is a special use case. I am in general happy with my settings, and I do not frequently want to change them as per use case (e.g. work / home). This is why I am looking for a key command etc. for this "special scenario music". But thanks a lot for pointing this out!

Comment: @shark that would work unless OP is using the internal speakers

Comment: @Raystafarian `do nothing` does exactly that ,it does nothing , so your speakers would work, closing the lid usually has a mechanical switch / sensor that just powers off the screen , everything else runs as is.

Comment: @Shark it would likely block the internal speakers, depending on where they are located.

Comment: @HorstWalter +1 for the research and editing your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Dekisoft's [Monitor Off Utility](http://www.dekisoft.com/mou.php) successfully before on desktops, but I can't promise that it'll function properly with the built in monitor on a laptop.  It's worth a try, though.  You can manually cut off the displays from the system tray or set up a hotkey for it.

Comment: Thanks, Monitor Off Utility and NirCmd work. IMHO MOUtility was easier to use since it comes with a GUI for all the settings. But this is just matter of my personal taste and laziness.

Answer (score 3):

Nirsofts [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) should do it for you , and there's a nifty trick for using it by [HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-off-the-monitor/)

Comment: Thanks, please see comment at "Monitor Off Utility". I appreciate your support.